# Trig Identities Question: $ \frac{\sin (4t)(1-\cos(2t))}{\cos (2t)(1-\cos(4t))}=\tan t$

Tags: trigonometry

Would you like to help me solving the following?
$$
\frac{\sin (4t)(1-\cos(2t))}{\cos (2t)(1-\cos(4t))}=\tan t, \quad 0<t<\frac{\pi}2,\,t\neq \frac{\pi}4.
$$
I managed to use trig identities to expand most of the equation but I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: The following two identities might help: $\sin 2a=2\sin a \cos a$ and $\sin^2a=\frac{1-\cos(2a)}2$.

Answer (score 1):

One may write, for appropriate values of $t$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin (4t)(1-\cos(2t))}{\cos (2t)(1-\cos(4t))}&=\frac{2\sin (2t)\cos(2t)(1-\cos(2t))}{\cos (2t)(1-\cos(4t))}
\\\\&=\frac{2\sin (2t)(1-\cos(2t))}{(1-\cos(4t))}
\\\\&=\frac{2\sin (2t)(2\sin^2(t))}{(2\sin^2(2t))}
\\\\&=\frac{2\sin^2(t)}{\sin(2t)}
\\\\&=\frac{2\sin^2(t)}{2\sin(t) \cos(t)}
\\\\&=\tan (t)
\end{align}
$$ as announced.